# Asp net Identity UserManager.IsEmailConfirmed return true and false on ConfirmEmail and Login

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

When I confirm an email and check is the email confirmed I get "true"

[image]

But when I try to login after the email confirmation, UserManager.IsEmailConfirmed returns "False"

Could anybody help me, please?

**Updated**

Ids the same.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Stupid question: are the IDs identical? Otherwise I can't see anything wrong in your code immediately.

Comment: @SergeyKudriavtsev, ids the same.

Comment: Okay, next step. Can you check what value do you have in the database? If you have `false`, it means that your `UserManager` doesn't save the value properly. If it's `true`, `UserManager` doesn't read the value properly. Finally, if it's `true` after save and `false` after read, it means that some other code is changing this value and you need to investigate which one.

Comment: @SergeyKudriavtsev, thank you for your answer. It is 'True', so I'll try to investigate where it's changing.

Comment: @MaksymLabutin what was your issue?

Comment: @gilmishal sorry, can't recall the solution...